# mxGraph image node edges

Tags: mxgraph

I am creating images nodes in mxGraph using following code.

```
var style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultVertexStyle();
style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE;
style[mxConstants.STYLE_IMAGE] = 'images/sourceIcon_Sample2.png;';

mxConstants.VERTEX_SELECTION_COLOR = '#FFFFFF';
```

under begin update

```
var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Obj1", 70, 130, width, height,"");
var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Obj2", 70, 130, width, height,"");
graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", v1, v2);
```

This creates my node properly at first but after I move the node the edges seems like it does not to the node. Please refer to the image below.

[image: Please look at the edge]

Now I understand that the edge is actually attached to the node but because of the image node it looks like this, but my question is can i avoid it ?

Or is there a way to use `shape=circle` and put image in it. I don't want to change the look of the graph and I am also supporting other shapes like hexagon with image, rectangle with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the perimeter style as follows:

```
style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = 'ellipsePerimeter'
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is solving my case